# Android to show notification at specific time

Tags: android, dialog, alert, android-alertdialog

I want to display alerts at specific times. So far I've made my class that extends `AlertDialog` but I cant seem to make it appear at specific time. How can I do it? And can I do it over an interval or for a set of time (if there is no interval between them)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use an `AlarmManager` and show your dialog when the alarm fires.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html